# Why does this rename operation not work?

Tags: bash, mv, patterns

This works:

```
$ touch abcdefg
$ mv -v abcdefg abc[de]fg
‘abcdefg’ -> ‘abc[de]fg’
```

But this doesn't work:

```
$ touch abcdefg
$ mv -v abcdefg abc[d]efg
mv: ‘abcdefg’ and ‘abcdefg’ are the same file
```

Why?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The shell will expand patterns according to filename.

- first form expands to `abcdfg` (no e) and/or `abcefg` (no d) and neither file exists, so the pattern is left unexpanded, and the command is what you think it is; effectively,

  ```
  mv -v "abcdefg" "abc[de]fg"
  ```
- second form expands to `abcdefg`, and this file exists, so the pattern expands to the file name, and thus the command is, effectively,

  ```
  mv -v abcdefg abcdefg
  ```

Try this to see when pattern is kept or expanded.

```
touch abcdefg
ls -l abc[de]fg ; echo abc[de]fg
ls -l abc??fg ;   echo abc??fg
ls -l abc?fg ;    echo abc?fg
ls -l abc[d]efg ; echo abc[d]efg
```

Comment: Also try: `touch abcdefg; touch abcdffg; echo abcd[efgh]fg`